# Unity Event destroys all GameObjects if there are more than two listeners

Tags: unity, c#

I've been writing a system where, if a raycast hits a 2D gameObject, a `UnityEvent` is fired and the `Shot()` method is executed. It works fine if the amount of listeners receiving the callback is equal to one, in this situation it destroys only clicked GameObject (which is what I need). As soon as you add another callback (AudioSource, Playing Particles), it destroys all GameObjects, which I don't want to be destroyed.

Class with Event:

```
public class ItemRaycastHit :  MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private UnityEvent _shot;
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
        {
            Vector2 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition); 
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(mousePos, Vector2.zero); 
            if (hit.collider.TryGetComponent<ClickableObject>(out ClickableObject clickable)) 
            {
                _shot?.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class ClickableObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Shot()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Image of the clickable object in inspector

[image: Inspector screenshot]

Comment: I notice that nowhere in this code do you tell the shot event which object you clicked. Did you mean to call `Shot()` only on the variable `clickable` representing the one object you clicked (ie `clickable.Shot()`), rather than on *every* clickable object subscribed to the `_shot` event?

Comment: Yes I need to call `Shot()` only on the `clickable` variable

Answer (score 0):

That is how it works. I'm not sure why you want to do this? You have a collider there, so just use the OnMouseDown event manager instead of the Update. See the example on the Unity manual: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you wanted to write this:

```
public class ItemRaycastHit :  MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private UnityEvent _shot;

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
        {
            Vector2 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition); 
            Collider2D hit = Physics2D.OverlapPoint(mousePos); 
            if (hit != null 
            && hit.TryGetComponent<ClickableObject>(out ClickableObject clickable)) 
            {
                // Invoke the Shot method on *only* 
                // the one ClickableObject that we clicked on.
                clickable.Shot();

                // Use our event to notify anything *that is NOT*
                // a ClickableObject that might want to also respond.
                _shot?.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can now remove your `ClickableObject`s from the list of listeners for the `_shot` event. We'll call their `Shot()` method directly when they're clicked. You can use the event to inform any third party that is not this script AND is not the object that was clicked.

I also changed your raycast code to an `OverlapPoint` check, since that expresses the intention more clearly than a raycast with no direction.